# Checking the code in parse.com cloud code

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform, cloud, parse-cloud-code

Im using parse.com cloud code -

Is there anyway to check your code there?

Something like breakpoint?

Im currently using `console.log` after every line in order to understand where i crash.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you ever notice exists some log here : https://www.parse.com/apps/YOUR_APP_NAME/cloud_code/log ?

Comment: sure but not about debug

Comment: If you provide some {{console.log}} within your parse cloud code, you should be able to output whatever you need. But my advice would be to use the CLI (Parse Command Line Tools) rather than output available on parse.com, it would be easier to track your breakpoint.

Comment: I don't understand - which tools?